# jquery htm5form validation

Tags: jquery

i'm using the html5form validation on my form, but i have one select box, where i choose the form i want to fill.

But my validation dont work... can help me?

my codes:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#box1').hide();
    $('#box2').hide();

    $("#curso_atual").change(function(){
        if(this.value == 'all'){
            $("#boxes").children().hide();
            } else {
            $("#" + this.value).show().siblings().hide();
        }
    });

    $('#box1').html5form({
            responseDiv : '#response',
            messages: 'br',
            colorOn :'#f4e6b2',
            colorOff :'#f4e6b2',
            allBrowsers : true,
        });

    });



</script>
```

`#box1` is my form id, and `#box2` is the ID for another form on the same page, i'm just show/hide with the select dropdown.

where i'm wrong? - My Fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/QyLfH/1/

Comment: A fiddle is always more helpful than raw code! http://jsfiddle.net

Comment: What exactly isn't working about it?

Comment: the validation, if you see, above the "Enviar" buttom, i have some yellow box. If you dont fill all fileds on the form, there's shows a mesage for this field...

Answer (score 1):

I solved the problem - http://jsfiddle.net/QyLfH/3/

here is the code:

```
$('#box1').hide();
$('#box2').hide();

$("#curso_atual").change(function(){
    if(this.value == 'all'){
        $("#boxes").children().hide();
        } else {
        $("#" + this.value).show().siblings().hide();
        $("#" + this.value).html5form({
                    responseDiv : '#response',
                    messages: 'br',
                    colorOn :'#000000',
                    colorOff :'#000000',
                    allBrowsers : true
         });
    }
});
```